# How to add new address for a existing customer through REST API

Tags: magento2, rest-api, address

I am facing one issue. Actually I have created first the customer profile using `magento2` through `REST API` but now I am trying to add the address for this existing profile but unable to do it. My code is given below.

```
$ent_id=44;
$customerData = [
        'customer' => [
            'addresses' => [
                [
                    "customer_id"=>$ent_id,
                    "firstname"=> $first_name,
                    "lastname"=> $last_name,
                    "company"=> $company,
                    "street"=> [
                    $street
                    ],
                    "city"=> $city,
                    "postcode"=> $pin,
                    "country_id"=> $country_id,
                    "telephone"=> $mobile
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ];
    $requestUrl='http://magento-148486-425775.cloudwaysapps.com/index.php/rest/V1/customers/'.$ent_id;
    //echo $requestUrl;exit;
    $ch = curl_init();
    $ch = curl_init($requestUrl); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($customerData));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " . json_decode($token))); 
    $result = curl_exec($ch); 

    $result = json_decode($result, 1);
    print_r($result);exit;
```

Actually here the `customer_id=44` which had created before for that customer I need to add address but it could not happen. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: do you have any error in the response json ?